# What is Angular's "unidirectional data flow rule"?

Tags: angular

Angular's "unidirectional data flow rule" is mentioned [several](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) [times](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) [in](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/enableProdMode-function.html) but nowhere do the Angular docs ever clearly (emphasis on **clearly**) *define* the unidirectional data flow rule.

Here are the closest things I could find to a clear definition of the unidirectional data flow rule:

From [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html):

> Angular's unidirectional data flow rule forbids updates to the view after it has been composed.

Fair enough, but what exactly does it mean for a view to have been composed? What constitutes an update to the view? Aren't we updating views all the time?

From [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/enableProdMode-function.html):

> One important assertion [enableProdMode] disables verifies that a change detection pass does not result in additional changes to any bindings (also known as unidirectional data flow).

I had to read this sentence about 8 times very slowly and I still don't get it. When it says "also known as unidirectional data flow", I'm assuming the thing that's also known as unidirectional data flow is "that a change detection pass does not result in additional changes to any bindings". Okay, maybe we're getting closer. Pretty abstract though. How about an example or something?

---

These two fairly opaque blurbs are all the Angular docs apparently give us to go off of regarding the unidirectional data flow rule. Seems insufficient.

Can anyone explain it to me more clearly, preferably as if I'm very stupid?

---

**Edit**: I found what might be a third clue, on [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html):

> A template expression should not change any application state other than the value of the target property.
>
> This rule is essential to Angular's "unidirectional data flow" policy. You should never worry that reading a component value might change some other displayed value. The view should be stable throughout a single rendering pass.

Okay. You should never worry that reading a component value might change some other displayed value. Is *that* Angular's unidirectional data flow rule? I wouldn't think so because it doesn't seem to agree with the other mentions of the rule. I'm still confused.

Comment: think of it kind of like the shadow dom in other frameworks. In simplified order, you have Change Detetction, then Composition (react to the changes), then Rendering (write the Composition to the DOM).  This all happens in cycles;  you don't want the act of Rendering to change anything that should have changed during Composition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Angular pre v1.5, two way binding was the norm, so if you created a child object in a component, the parent maintained a reference to it, so if you updated the object in the parent, it updated the child, and if you updated the object in the child, it updated the parent. This incurred a lot of overhead, and you'd see significant performance impact with a large number of child components maintaining two way bindings to the parent, for example, a parent container component loading a list of passenger data and displaying a child component for each passenger with the specific attributes for that passenger. The parent is watched for changes, and every child is watched for changes, and they're constantly being re-evaluted.

One way data binding was introduced in Angular1.5, but is a big part of Angular2's performance gains. Data flows from the parent to the child, but not the other way round. If the parent data changes, those changes are pushed down to the child, but if the child changes, those changes are not auto-magically propagated back to the parent. You manage updates from the child to the parent by explicitly sending an event back up to the parent with the changed data, and instructing the parent to update the specific data that's changed. One way data flow then takes over and the parent, with updated data, updates the children as appropriate.

Comment: I am not an Angular expert, please bear with my question. In terms of "those changes are not auto-magically propagated back to the parent". However, if we make a two-way data binding in Angular 2+. It does the same thing, which violates the above statement. Please let me know if I am holding a false view.

Comment: I don't use two-way data binding in Angular. Enabling two-way data binding does propagate changes in the child to the parent, and does violate the above statement, which is precisely why I don't do it. If a child component mutates data, it should send an event back to the parent either with the mutated data, or with instructions to refetch the data it has changed and saved, and then the changed data is propagated from the parent down the stack to its children. In one parent/one child sets, there's no performance hit, but in parent-to-many-child sets, two-way binding is a huge performance hit.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have heard that Angular 2 has improved its change detection mechanism. In terms of two-way data binding in Angular, do you think it works better than Angular JS? (I have worked with Angular JS for 1 Year & have been working with Angular 5 since 2018 May. I have felt that Angular 2 is for more ahead in performance wise)

Answer (score 0):

The "unidirectional data flow" is referring to the underlying Change Detection process. So the answer to the quesion.....

> You should never worry that reading a component value might change some other displayed value. Is that Angular's unidirectional data flow rule?

...... is Yes.

During the change detection phase, Angular will check to see if a variable referenced in an expression in the template has changed. If it has, this new value is inserted into the HTML. While this check is occurring, the 'getter' function, or expression should not change any other values.

It's the No Side Effects section of
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-guidelines

Very good article (Thoughtram.io)
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

> The reason why data flows from top to bottom, is because change
>   detection is also always performed from top to bottom for every single
>   component, every single time, starting from the root component. This
>   is awesome, as **unidirectional data flow** is more predictable than
>   cycles. We always know where the data we use in our views comes from,
>   because it can only result from its component.
>
> Another interesting observation is that change detection gets stable
>   after a single pass. Meaning that, if one of our components causes any
>   additional side effects after the first run during change detection,
>   Angular will throw an error